# How to get the maximum of single values within matrix multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix, max

I have two matrices m1 and m2:

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1,2, 0,2, 1,1), ncol=3, nrow=2)
m2 <- matrix(c(1,1,1, 3,3,3), ncol=2, nrow=3)
```

Multiplication results in:

```
m3 <- (m1%*%m2)
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    6
[2,]    5   15
```

Now instead of giving the the sum product in the matrix m3, I want R to give me the MAX value of the corresponding multiplication process, e.g.:

```
for MAX[1,1]=(1+0+1)=1
for MAX[1,2]=(3+0+3)=3
for MAX[2,1]=(2+2+1)=2
for MAX[2,2]=(6+6+3)=6
```

which I want to result in the following matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    6
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over it on your own, e.g.

```
out <- sapply(1:nrow(m1), function(i) {
  sapply(1:ncol(m2), function(j){
    max(m1[i, ] * m2[, j])
  })
})

t(out)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    6
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!